# Can i have url with two handlers?

Tags: jquery, html, css, url, frontend

On one page of a website there are tabs  and every tab have own id, so you can call direct every tab by make http://www.example.com/page#tab1.

The problem is that i want to make url that will open not the begining of the tab but the specific content which is in the middle of the content and also have id, because is dropdown.

Can I make wlink which will open the specific tab but also will scroll to other id or atleast for example will prescrool 200px?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very experienced but I saw your question and I got curious about whether or not this could be done and how.

If I've got this right you have elements #tab1 #tab2 etc and want to be able to point to a certain element inside them. Like #tab1 > #element1, #tab1 > #element2 etc. You also have implemented a tab system that works with the URL.
A little more context about why you need to do this and on what situation would be really useful to be honest but I'm gonna give you my best shot.

First thing I can think of (and I've got idea if this is a good practice or not) would be to check and save hashes one URL and use and use scrollTop method accordingly.

Anyway, I took this https://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/jGzuK simple tab system made using jQuery and I tried to make it work with two hashes on URL.

***For this I had to download the code from codepen and put up a single index.html file with everything to try this since I have no idea how to handle hashes on URL with codepen.***

All I had to do is tweak the JS a little and add more elements to the tabs so the page going to a certain anchor would be noticeable. Here's my updated JS here:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){ //this simply make the tab system work. It's from the codepen.
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})

if(document.location.hash) { //now let's check if there's a hash
      var u = window.location.hash.substring(1);; //And if so let's puts hash in variable 
      hash = u.split('#'); //split it by # character and save it as an array 

      var element =  jQuery('#'+hash[0]); //now let's set that first hash as current tab
      $('.tab-content').removeClass('current'); //but first remove the curent classes first
      $('.tab-link').removeClass('current');           
      element.addClass('current');
      $("[data-tab="+hash[0]+"]").addClass('current'); //done selecting the tab using hash from URL

      if(hash[1]) { // now! if there's another hash in the URL
        var subElement = $('#'+hashes[1]);
        var goToElement = subElement.offset().top; 

        $(window).scrollTop(goToElement);//go there!
      }
```

Now if I try accesing /index.html#tab-4#element it takes me to a at the bottom of the 4th tab.

It's a super rough idea without knowing where you're at or what you're done and still needs work. If you could provide some code helping you will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't combine multiple ids in the hash, instead I would search for the element with the `id` defined by the hash of the url and then traverse the DOM up using e.g. `.closest('.tab-element')` until you reach the root of the DOM to check if you need to switch one or more tabs, switch to those tabs and then scroll the element into the visible part of the screen.

Solving it that way would make your code most likely easier to maintain, because you do not need to care about how the elements are nested.

How you do this exactly depends on how you have implemented you tabs.